# Comparing structs in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-3, compute-shader

Is it safe to compare two structs of the same type by using the classic equality operator? I haven't found any information about this and there is no option to overload this operator in GLSL. So does GLSL compare two structs component-wise by default?

```
struct sith
{
   int forceLevel;
   vec3 saberColor;
};
...
sith vader = sith(100,vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0));
sith anakin = sith(100,vec3(1.0,0.0,0.0));
...
if (vader == anakin)
   //is the force strong with this one?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When using the equality operators, two structures are equal if and only if all the fields are
>   component-wise equal, and two arrays are equal if and only if all the elements are element-wise equal

- [*GLSL 1.30 Specification, Page 46, Section 5.7 "Structure and Array Operations"*](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.30.pdf#page=52)

Comment: Aah thank you very much. I went through the wrong sections and didn't notice this one.